# What are the magic tables available in SQL Server 2000?

Tags: sql-server

What are the magic tables available in SQL Server 2000?

I wonder, why they are 'magic' tables?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'magic tables' are the **INSERTED** and **DELETED** tables, as well as the **update()** and **columns_updated()** functions, and are used to determine the changes resulting from DML statements.

- For an INSERT statement, the INSERTED table will contain the inserted rows.
- For an UPDATE statement, the INSERTED table will contain the rows after an update, and the DELETED table will contain the rows before an update.
- For a DELETE statement, the DELETED table will contain the rows to be deleted.

The primary use of these tables are for more complex operations when triggers are fired.

Answer (score 1):

GIYF:

> The INSERTED and DELETED tables,
>   popularly known as MAGIC TABLES, and
>   update () and columns_updated()
>   functions can be used to determine the
>   changes being caused by the DML
>   statements.