# sql update query that creates history for a same record

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have an `enquiry details` table and in this the user needs to update their status for the particular enquiry. If I use update statement it overwrites the previous status update.

What I need is

```
sno     confname         region       enquiry   status update    date of update
 1     Vision 2020   Madhya Pradesh    test    have to follow     16/03/2013
                                                next week     
 1     Vision 2020    Madhya Pradesh   test    Confirmed the
                                                product. Product  20/03/2013
                                                to be deliver.
```

But I am getting now is

```
sno     confname         region       enquiry   status update    date of update
 1     Vision 2020    Madhya Pradesh   test    Confirmed the
                                                product. Product  20/03/2013
                                                to be deliver.
```

I need to get the history of the particular enquiry..

I would appreciate your input and help.

Comment: i did suggest you to create a new table where all the history is maintained. now your `sno` might be your `primary key`, in such a scenario what you want to achieve is not possible.

Comment: i am having timestamp field for each enquiry too..

Comment: thats allright...you will get all the fields you want...can you create a similar table structure on your DataBase...or in my anmswer i will also show you how to replicate that same table.

Comment: i just created a similar table structure..now you guide me how to proceed..

Comment: check my answer...you are all good to go

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can achieve what you want. Using a `TRIGGER`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigg_TriggerName
ON yourFIRSTTableName
AFTER UPDATE
AS

INSERT INTO yourSECONDTableName
    SELECT * FROM DELETED
```

Just create a `trigger` like this. So whenever you do an `update` on your parent table, your second table will be `inserted` with old records from your parent table.

Also if you want to know more about what `DELETED` is, know more about [MAGIC TABLES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851189/what-are-the-magic-tables-available-in-sql-server-2000) here

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to have a seperated history table, and instead of using TRIGGER, every time when you do the update, use [update ... output delete.* into history table]