# Magic tables without triggers use , no explanation found even on stackoverfloflow

Tags: sql-server

I have read a lot of articles like

[What are the magic tables available in SQL Server 2000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851189/what-are-the-magic-tables-available-in-sql-server-2000)

http://www.consultmachine.com/2017/07/06/magic-tables-in-sql-server/

https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/285423/what-is-magic-table-different-types-of-magic-table

But no one explians NON TRIGGER USE of MAGIC TABLES , I AM STRUGGLING FROM A WEEK.

Comment: "Magic tables" isn't a term ever used by MS themselves to describe the tables, so far as I'm aware. They're just referred to be their names (`inserted` and `deleted`). "without triggers" - are you looking for the [`OUTPUT` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql)?

Comment: Without triggers i mean, any example of using magic table ( excluding inserted and deleted in SPs). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few examples of using the OUTPUT clause w/o using a trigger...

```
USE AlignDev;
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ChangeTracking', 'U') IS NULL 
BEGIN   -- DROP TABLE #ChangeTracking
    CREATE TABLE #ChangeTracking (
        ChangeDT DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT (GETDATE()),
        oID INT NULL,
        nID INT NULL,
        oCol_1 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
        nCol_1 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
        oCol_2 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
        nCol_2 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
        oCol_3 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
        nCol_3 VARCHAR(10) NULL
        );
END;


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TestData', 'U') IS NULL 
BEGIN   -- DROP TABLE #TestData
    CREATE TABLE #TestData (
        ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
        Col_1 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
        Col_2 VARCHAR(10) NULL,
        Col_3 VARCHAR(10) NULL
        );
END

--=================================================================

INSERT #TestData (Col_1, Col_2, Col_3) 
OUTPUT Inserted.* INTO #ChangeTracking (nID, nCol_1, nCol_2, nCol_3)
    SELECT 'abc', 'def', 'ghi' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'jkl', 'mno', '123' UNION ALL 
    SELECT '346', '789', 'qaz' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'wsx', 'edc', 'rfv' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'tgb', 'yhn', 'ujm' UNION ALL 
    SELECT 'plm', 'uhb', 'tfc';

-- see what's been captured so far...
SELECT * FROM #TestData td;
SELECT * FROM #ChangeTracking ct;

------------------------------------------------

UPDATE td SET 
    td.Col_1 = 'xxx',
    td.Col_3 = 'zzz'
    OUTPUT Deleted.*, Inserted.*
    INTO #ChangeTracking (oID, oCol_1, oCol_2, oCol_3, nID, nCol_1, nCol_2, nCol_3)
FROM 
    #TestData td
WHERE 
    td.ID IN (2, 4, 6);

-- see what's been captured so far...
SELECT * FROM #TestData td;
SELECT * FROM #ChangeTracking ct;

------------------------------------------------

DELETE td
OUTPUT Deleted.* INTO #ChangeTracking ( oID, oCol_1, oCol_2, oCol_3)
FROM 
    #TestData td;

-- see what's been captured so far...
SELECT * FROM #TestData td;
SELECT * FROM #ChangeTracking ct;
```

HTH,
Jason